# Preserve ${name} in Url.Action route values for use with jquery.tmpl?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, urlencode, jquery-templates

I'm venturing a bit off the beaten path here, but it doesn't seem too unreasonable.

In a view, with this code:

```
<div>Hello ${Name}</div>
```

Ran through jquery.tmpl supplied with { Id: **1**, Name = "**Bob**" }, will render the following on the client:

```
<div>Hello Bob</div>
```

**This is great and all, but let's introduce a Url:**

In a view, with this code:

```
<div>Hello <a href="<%: Url.Action("Profile", new { id= "${Id}" }) %>">${Name}</a></div>
```

Renders to:

```
<div>Hello <a href="/User/Profile?id=%24%7BId%7D">${Name}</a></div>
```

And after ran through jquery.tmpl the encoded Id tag doesn't get picked up:

```
 <div>Hello <a href="/User/Profile?id=%24%7BId%7D">Bob</a></div>
```

I understand why this is happening, but what I'm struggling with is a way to prevent Route Values from being encoded. I lose the trail after digging around in the de-compiled code for some time, the actual mechanism for encoding eludes me. If it were me, I'd convert the Route Values to an `HttpNameCollection` and `ToString` it, such as using `HttpUtility.Parse()`.

MVC has been amazingly flexible with things like this so I find it hard to believe I can't change the encoder or wrap route value values with an `MvcHtmlString` or something.

How can I get a Url.Action, either be from a UrlHelper extensions or replaced and extended encoder, preserve route values with the jquery.tmpl formats: `${value}`

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest way, but you could wrap it within a `Server.UrlDecode` function. So your code would look like

```
<a href="<%: Server.UrlDecode(Url.Action("Profile", new { id= "${Id}" })) %>">${Name}</a>
```

This would output `/User/Profile?id=${id}`

An alternate way is to create your own Html Helper which will return the RAW input rather than encoding it. I had to do something similar with the `ActionLink`. Take a look at my blog post about it. [MVC ActionLink with HTML Content.](http://timjames.me/mvc-actionlink-with-html-content)